# python generator in class

Tags: python, class, generator

I am learning generator from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python). This is really a good example for generator. But I am confused by one of the example code.

```
>>> class Bank(): # let's create a bank, building ATMs
...    crisis = False
...    def create_atm(self):
...        while not self.crisis:
...            yield "$100"
>>> hsbc = Bank() # when everything's ok the ATM gives you as much as you want
>>> corner_street_atm = hsbc.create_atm()
>>> print(corner_street_atm.next())  
$100  
>>> print(corner_street_atm.next())  
$100  
>>> print([corner_street_atm.next() for cash in range(5)])  
['$100', '$100', '$100', '$100', '$100']  
>>> hsbc.crisis = True # crisis is coming, no more money!  
>>> print(corner_street_atm.next())  
<type 'exceptions.StopIteration'>   
>>> wall_street_atm = hsbc.create_atm() # it's even true for new ATMs  
>>> print(wall_street_atm.next())  
<type 'exceptions.StopIteration'>  

>>> hsbc.crisis = False # trouble is, even post-crisis the ATM remains empty
>>> print(corner_street_atm.next())
<type 'exceptions.StopIteration'>

>>> brand_new_atm = hsbc.create_atm() # build a new one to get back in business
>>> for cash in brand_new_atm:
...    print cash
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
...
```

When **hsbc.crisis** is reset to **False**, the **corner_steet_atm** can not yield anything but StopIteration.
Why does this happen. I think the corner_street_atm is not empty after crisis.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is coming from the fact that when you say

```
corner_street_atm = hsbc.create_atm()
```

You are calling the function once, and that is all the times it will be called.  Thus, let's keep a view of what is happening

```
  def create_atm(self):
        # Called right away, when you say the above line and only then
        print("Called function") 

        # Loops while crisis = False
        while not self.crisis: 
            yield "$100"
```

Now, we can ask the question of where our method is looking when crisis is True, and we find that it is point at the spot shown below:

```
  def create_atm(self):
        # Called right away, when you say the above line and only then
        print("Called function") 

        # Loops while crisis = False
        while not self.crisis: 
            yield "$100"
            #<------ Where you function points after you set crisis to false and get the next
```

Well, there is nothing there, so you get an error.

What you are really looking for appears to be an infinite loop in atm.  Something like this:

```
class Bank():
    crisis = False

    def create_atm(self):
        print("Called function")
        while True:
            if not self.crisis:
                yield "$100"
            else:
                yield "$0"
```

Careful with this, as your final call

```
for cash in brand_new_atm:
    print(cash)
```

will loop forever because you currently don't see how much cash is in the atm (So as long as there isn't a crisis it will just spew out dollar bills.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is due to that you called the `corner_street_atm.next()` after you set the `hsbc.crisis=True`. If you do it like this, you would have no problem:

```
hsbc.crisis=False

corner_street_atm = hsbc.create_atm()

hsbc.crisis=True

hsbc.crisis=False

corner_street_atm.next()
Out[54]: '$100'
```

The reason is the the `corner_street_atm` is a generator(iterator) object, and once The generator created in this case will call o with no arguments for each call to its next() method; if the value returned is equal to sentinel, `StopIteration` will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned<sup>[[1]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter)</sup>.

The thing is once you call the `corner_street_atm.next()` after the `hsbc.crisis=True`, the Exception will be raised. And once the exception is raised, there is not way to loop this object any more and unless you create a new object!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your generator (which is a type of iterator) has been exhausted. Once it has been exhausted, an iterator should not flip back and forth between yielding values and raising the `StopIteration` (in other words your example is behaving as it should even though it isn't what you want it to do). Here is some more about the iterator protocol:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators

The reason the generator stops yielding values in this particular case is that once you exit the `while` loop (which happens as soon as `next` is called when `'crisis'` is True), there is no way to re enter the loop.

What you most likely want to be doing is using the `__iter__` magic method on a separate `ATM` object. More about that here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter

It might look something like this:

```
class ATM():
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.owner = owner
    def __iter__(self):
        yield "$100"
    def __call__(self):
        if self.owner.crisis is True:
            return 'crisis!'

class Bank(): # let's create a bank, building ATMs
    crisis = False
    def create_atm(self):
        return ATM(self)
```

You'll want to get an atm iterator this way:

```
>>> hsbc = Bank() 
>>> corner_street_atm = hsbc.create_atm() # this way
>>> corner_street_atm = ATM(hsbc) # or this way
>>> corner_street_atm_iterator = iter(corner_street_atm, 'crisis!')
```

The last line uses an optional form of the `iter` function since a second argument is supplied. The iterator returned by this second form raises `StopIteration` if `corner_street_atm.__call__()` returns the sentinel value that was supplied to `iter`. In this case the sentinel is `'crisis!'`.

And iterate through it like this:

```
>>> print(corner_street_atm_iterator.next())  
$100
```

NOTE: an `ATM` object never runs out of money if you don't use `iter` with the `'crisis!'` sentinel argument!

```
infinite_atm_iterator = iter(ATM(some_bank))
```